# String Template: is it possible to get the n-th element of a Java List in the template?

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

In String Template one can easily get an element of a Java Map within the template.
Is it possible to get the n-th element of an array in a similar way?

According to the [String Template Cheat Sheet](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet) you can easily get the first or second element:

> You can combine operations to say things like first(rest(names)) to get second element.

but it doesn't seem possible to get the n-th element easily. I usually transform my list into a map with list indexes as keys and do something like

```
map.("25")
```

Is there some easier/more straightforward way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, there is no mechanism to get a[i].

Comment: Ok. Sounds like a nice idea for a feature request. Thanks for yet another fast answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way getting n-th element of the list.

In my opinion this indicates that your view and business logic are not separated enough: knowledge of what magic number 25 means is spread in both tiers.

One possible solution might be converting list of values to object which provides meaning to the elements. For example, lets say list of String represents address lines, in which case instead of `map.("3")` you would write `address.street`.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) I wrote that question 3 months ago so I don't really remember anymore why I needed this particular functionality so it will be hard to determine if the view and BL were not separated enough. If I remember some time later, I will let you know so that we can discuss further.